# 1 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/en/index.html"

Tags: nginx, angular, i18n

I want to host the Angular i18n website using the Nginx proxy.

As per the official Nginx configuration suggestion https://angular.io/guide/i18n-common-deploy#nginx-example, my `app.conf` file in the `/etc/nginx/site-available` directory is like

```
map $http_accept_language $accept_language {
        ~*^de de;
        ~*^fr fr;
        ~*^en en;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name i18n.example.io;
    root /var/www/html/app/dist/app;

    # Fallback to default language if no preference defined by browser
    if ($accept_language ~ "^$") {
        set $accept_language "en";
    }

    # Redirect "/" to Angular application in the preferred language of the browser
    rewrite ^/$ /$accept_language permanent;

    # Everything under the Angular application is always redirected to Angular in the
    # correct language
    location ~ ^/(fr|de|en) {
        try_files $uri /$1/index.html?$args;
    }
}
```

But when I try to access my website `http://i18n.example.com`, it gives the following error in the `error.log` file

```
2022/07/15 20:19:15 [error] 16886#16886: *1 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/en/index.html", client: xx.xxx.235.xx, server: i18n.example.io, request: "GET /en HTTP/1.1", host: "i18n.example.io"
```

Comment: can you modify `try_files` to `try_files $uri /$1/index.html?$args =404;`, restart nginx, and try again?

Comment: Not it gives `404 Not Found`.

Comment: You need to use `try_files $uri /$1/index.html =404;`

Answer (score 1):

> can you modify `try_files` to `try_files $uri /$1/index.html?$args =404;`, restart nginx, and try again?

> Not it gives `404 Not Found`.

> ```
> map $http_accept_language $accept_language {
>     ~*^de de;
>     ~*^fr fr;
>     ~*^en en;
> }
>
> server {
>     ...
>     root /var/www/html/app/dist/app;
>
>     ...
>     if ($accept_language ~ "^$") {
>         set $accept_language "en";
>     }
> ```

according to your configuration, when you send requests to nginx with URL `http://i18n.example.com`, nginx will try to append language code (`en`/`fr`/`de`) according to `Accept-Language` HTTP header sent by your user agent.
when there's no such header exists, nginx will by default append `en` language code.

> ```
>     rewrite ^/$ /$accept_language permanent;
>     location ~ ^/(fr|de|en) {
>         try_files $uri /$1/index.html?$args;
>     }
> ```

nginx then does an internal redirect to `http://i18n.example.com/<language code>` and evaluates `location ~ ^/(fr|de|en)` successfully.

for example, let's use `en` language code, so then the internal redirect points to `http://i18n.example.com/en`.

using this URI and your `try_files $uri /$1/index.html?$args` configuration, nginx will try to access `http://i18n.example.com/en` and `http://i18n.example.com/en/index.html?<argument>`; which translates to `/var/www/html/app/dist/app/en` and `/var/www/html/app/dist/app/en/index.html` respectively.

if no such file exists, which is happening in your current situation, your `location ~ ^/(fr|de|en)` will be re-triggered again since there's two requests to `/en`. this will create redirection loop inside nginx and it'll break out from the loop by sending an error.

to solve this, either check if you have `/var/www/html/app/dist/app/en/index.html` file available and readable by nginx, or add `=404` to your `try_files` configuration to let it gracefully fail as 404 error.